Django forms: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed
This is my first real project and im excited, strggling though, its supposed to have a count of the type of access for a gym.
Im trying to make a form, it seems that theres a problem with Datefield
Heres the form:

from django import forms
from django.db import models

class create_client(forms.Form):
nombre= forms.CharField(label='Nombre', max_length=50)
telefono=forms.CharField(label='Telefono', max_length=50)
domicilio=forms.CharField(label='Domicilio', max_length=50)
fecha_nacimmiento=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
email=forms.CharField(label='email', max_length=50)
numero_emergencia=forms.CharField(label='No.Emegencia', max_length=50)
discapacidad_alergia=forms.CharField(label='Discapacidad/Alergias', max_length=50)


Heres my views:
from .models import Cliente, Mensualidades, Cuponera, Daypass, Bloques
from django.shortcuts  import render, redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import create_client

def index(request):
    username='Jorge Angulo Villeda (@newdibranch_) angulovilleda@hotmail.com'
    return render(request, 'index.html',
    {'username':username})

def accesos(request):
    username='Jorge Angulo Villeda (@newdibranch_) angulovilleda@hotmail.com'
    mensualidades = Mensualidades.objects.all()
    cuponeras = Cuponera.objects.all()
    today = timezone.now().date()
    daypass_hoy = Daypass.objects.filter(fecha_acceso=today)
    return render(request,'accesos.html',
    {'cuponeras': cuponeras,
    'mensualidades': mensualidades,
    'daypass_hoy': daypass_hoy,
    'username':username})

def about(request):
    username='Jorge Angulo Villeda (@newdibranch_) angulovilleda@hotmail.com'
    return render(request,'about.html',
    {'username':username})

def clientes(request):
    username='Jorge Angulo Villeda (@newdibranch_) angulovilleda@hotmail.com'
    clientes = Cliente.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'clientes.html',{
        'clientes': clientes,
        'form': create_client()
     })
    else:
        Cliente.objects.create(nombre=request.POST['nombre'],telefono=request.POST['telefono'])

I think the error  is Raised during:  myapp.views.clientes
**Models:
**
from typing import Any
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.utils import timezone


class Cliente(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='ingresar nombre')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20,db_index=True,default='ingresar telefono')
    domicilio = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='ingresar domicilio')
    fecha_nacimiento= models.DateField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='ingresar email')
    numero_emergencia = models.CharField(max_length=20,db_index=True,default='ingresar telefono')
    discapacidad_alergia = models.CharField(max_length=200,db_index=True,default='ingresar info.')
   
    mensualidad_activa = models.BooleanField(default=False)  
    cuponera_activa = models.BooleanField(default=False)   

   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
